# Want to drain/change compressor oil, but there's no outlet

Tags: tools, compressor, air-compressor

I have an air compressor; the brand was supposedly Karson but it's actually a rebranded Fiac compressor. I wanted to change the oil; but I realized that it has a window-level, no actual dipstick and also there is no oil outlet. I feel like I'm being trolled.

See the pictures for reference.

[image: Label]
[image: Oil cap]
[image: Oil level and no outlet]

Answer (score 4):

If there's a window, you don't need a dipstick.

If there's no lower outlet, open the inlet and turn it over. Or, suck it out (auto parts stores typically have something for doing that.)

Compressor oil changing does not need to be especially convenient as it's relatively infrequent, and the scale of compressor you show is not impossible to turn over by hand - so, no drain plug = one less place to leak, not "trolling"

Comment: I mean yeah, I guess. But it's odd when the manual shows four or five different compressor models and they all have an outlet. I've also seen this exact compressor elsewhere on the internet except it has an outlet; it's weird to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that window unscrews and is located near the bottom of the crank-case,
there's your drain plug,

Comment: I actually thought about unscrewing it but decided not to since other versions I've seen of the same compressor have an additional drain below that window.